# Install Allure in other (not Debian) GNU/Linux distributions

Tags: linux, allure

Looking to [Allure installation instructions](https://docs.qameta.io/allure/#_installing_a_commandline), with regards to GNU/Linux, only a procedure for Debian is provided.

Is is possible to install Allure in other GNU/Linux distributions (e.g. CentOS 7)?

Comment: You know system administration questions are [OT here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install it under other distributions you need to follow the steps under "Manual Installation"

> 2.1.4. Manual installation
>
> Download the latest version as zip archive from bintray.
>
> Unpack the archive to allure-commandline directory.
>
> Navigate to bin directory.
>
> Use allure.bat for Windows or allure for other Unix platforms.
>
> Add allure to system PATH.

Or you can use *.deb file unpackers/converters